# How to show albums in footer area of website rather than showing images of galleries in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working with word press 3.8 and using NEXT ZEN gallery for creating gallery and albums.
My question is that: How to show albums in footer area of website rather than showing the images of galleries

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to go their documentation page and see if there's a way. If none, then your only option is to edit the plugin to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your time.
By the way I have solved the issue.
What I did is just put the shortcode as folows:

`<?php echo do_shortcode('[album id=2]'); ?>` 
wherever(in my case it was footer_sidebar) you want to show the albums.